# Gauche "unknown module" using `import` with a built-in module

Tags: import, module, scheme, gauche

I am attempting to follow the Gauche manual to write a simple toy script, but I am struggling with the Gauche `import` mechanism.

Here is my script, `random-team-member`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gosh

(import (data.random :only (samples$)))

(define team-members
  (list "billy"
        "nilly"
        "silly"
        "willy"))

(define (generator->first gen)
  (car (generator->list gen 1)))

(define (sample1 items)
  (generator->first (samples$ items)))

(define (main args)
  (print (sample1 team-members)))
```

But I get the error `ERROR: unknown module data.random`.

As far as I could tell from the docs ([here](https://practical-scheme.net/gauche/man/gauche-refe/Modules.html#Predefined-modules) and [here](https://practical-scheme.net/gauche/man/gauche-refe/Random-data-generators.html#Random-data-generators)), this is the correct syntax for `import`, and `data.random` is indeed the name of the module.

I also tried defining a Gauche module, thinking that maybe `import` only worked inside a `define-module` definition, but that didn't change the error:

```lisp
(define-module random-team-member
  (import (data.random :only (samples$))))

(select-module random-team-member)

; ... the rest of my code ...
```

I am using Gauche 0.9.12, installed on MacOS (ARM64) using Homebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use R7RS style `import`:

```lisp
(import (only (data random) samples$))
```

which puts Gauche into R7RS user mode as a side-effect. To remain in Gauche user mode and use its style of `import`, first you have to [`require`](https://practical-scheme.net/gauche/man/gauche-refe/Loading-Programs.html#index-require) the file that defines the module:

```lisp
(require "data/random")
(import (data.random :only (samples$)))
```

but it's often simpler to use [`use`](https://practical-scheme.net/gauche/man/gauche-refe/Modules.html#index-use), which requires the file for you based on the module name:

```lisp
(use data.random :only (samples$))
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't think this usage was particularly clear from the manual.

Comment: @shadowtalker Yeah, it's not explained very well.